# replacing os.system with subprocess.call with shell=False

Tags: python, python-2.7

Want to replace 
os.system with subprocess.call() :-

code to be modified:-

```
os.system('if [ -e python ]; then mv -f test.txt /someURL/ ; fi')
```

I tried:-

```
subprocess.call('if [ -e python ]; then mv -f test.txt /someURL/ ; fi',shell=False)

subprocess.call(shlex.split('if [ -e python ]; then mv -f test.txt /someURL/ ; fi'),shell=False)
```

but getting error in both cases:-

```
subprocess.call('if [ -e python ]; then mv -f test.txt /someURL/ ; fi',shell=False)
File "/usr/lib64/python2.7/subprocess.py", line 524, in call
return Popen(*popenargs, **kwargs).wait()
File "/usr/lib64/python2.7/subprocess.py", line 711, in __init__
errread, errwrite)
File "/usr/lib64/python2.7/subprocess.py", line 1327, in _execute_child
raise child_exception
OSError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory
```

Comment: Provide the whole path and test

Comment: i have specified whole path, but its not working. This command works with shell=True. but not with shell=False, so need a workaround for this as with shell=True this command is vulnerable to command injection

Comment: Can you please show me the full path you made?

Comment: Sure , its :-     subprocess.call('if [ -e python ]; then mv -f test.txt /daa/shared/paj/clone/test/python/ ; fi',shell=False)

Comment: Provide full path like this:  `C:/..../daa/shared/....`

Comment: but then how is it executing with shell=True, actually i cant specify the whole path here. if i use shell=True then it executes successfully.

Comment: `if` is a shell statement, you can't execute that with `shell=False`. IMHO, han solo's answer is spot-on: if you want to avoid `shell=True` you should implement the logic of that `if` in python. The general answer to the question "how to execute a shell script using `subprocess.call` and `shell=False`" is "you can't" (or actually you can... just use `subprocess.call(['sh', '-c', <script>])` but then what's the point of having `shell=False`?

Answer (score 3):

I think, it is best to use `python` for the whole thing rather than using any `shell` functionality, because the question certainly doesn't show any shell requirements,

```
import os
import shutil

if os.path.exists('/usr/bin/python'):
    shutil.move("path/to/current/file.foo", "path/to/new/destination/for/file.foo")
```

Comment: This doesn't answer OP's question.

Comment: @BlackThunder `if`, `then`, `else` are shell constructs and certainly not a command. If the user want to achieve that without using any `shell`, i'd say it is pretty close to impossible :)